# Vertical alignment of text in Button in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-button, android-tablelayout, text-alignment

I have a `TableLayout` full of `Button`s (a grid of buttons), which may or may not have wrapped text. By default, the baseline of the first line of text is used as the vertical alignment point, so the buttons are not all equally vertically spaced in a perfect grid. What property will center the text vertically and force the buttons into a perfect grid?

I've already tried combinations of:

```
tableLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // for all buttons
button.setIncludeFontPadding(false); // for all buttons
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `android:baselineAligned` attribute of `TableRow`s containing the `Button`s to `false`:

```
tableRow.setBaselineAligned(false);
```

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/BN6WKNzXKWE

Comment: Setting that property on the `TableRow` worked (but not on `TableLayout`)! If you modify your answer to reflect that I'll accept it. Thanks.